# Best practice on scoping fields defined inside Scala object

Tags: scala

I have fields defined inside object as you can see below. If we define scope at object level we can ensure that all the fields are not usable outside of desired package without explicitly defining scope of each fields within object. If this is the desired behavior (inheriting scoping at object level) is this correct approach? Also instead of scoping at object level, is it best practice to scope at field level?

This is redundant

```
package com.temp

private[temp] object SomeObject {
  private[temp] field1: Long = ???
}
```

This is desired?

```
package com.temp

private[temp] object SomeObject {
  field1: Long = ???
}
```

Comment: The second one is not equivalent to the first one. The second one allows using the `SomeObject` in the `temp` package but doesn't allow accessing to the `field1` field. But yeah, the first one is redundant.

Comment: Using SomeObject in temp is desired, and in fact all the fields defined inside SomeObject should be accessible to temp unless scoped private.

Comment: Yeah just make the whole `object` `private[temp]` and leave everything inside as _public_ unless it should be `private`.